# I have something to ask, i just learned how to use while loops, and i encountered a problem. Why does the 2 of these have different ending

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

```
myage = 20
grandmaage = 25

while grandmaage > myage:
     print(myage)
     myage +=1
     
while grandmaage > myage:
     myage += 1
     print(myage)
```

The first while statement prints out

```
20
21
22
23
24
```

The second while statement prints out

```
21
22
23
24
25
```

I kind of undestand why they start differently 20 and 21, but why do they end differently 24 and 25.
I am very sorry my english is not very good.
Thank you very much

Comment: In your second code when myage is 24 and grandmas ages is 25 your loop is still true so you enter it again, you then increase myage to 25 before printing, then you print it. I.E you evaluated the condition 25 > 24 then increase myage to 25 and print my age. thats why it prints 25 at the end.

Comment: The value of the variable is the same in both cases each time through the loop, it's just that in the first case you print it on the screen before it increases, and in the other you print it after the increase. Each time through the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to apologize for anything.

In the first code you first print the value of the variable and then add one to it, so in the last round you print 24 then add 1 to it and leave the variable as 25.
but the second code add 1 and the print the value.
that is why the beginning of out puts are also different! both loops starts with 20 but the sequence of adding and print is different!

please do not hesitate to ask any other ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

In the first approach, you're printing before incrementing the `age`:

```
print(myage)
myage +=1
```

In the second approach, you're incrementing first and then priting:

```
myage += 1
print(myage)
```

So there comes a iteration when the age is `24` and the condition is still true i.e. `25 > 24` and inside the loop, you increment it again to `25` and print it.

The value of the variable `age` stays the same in both approaches, it is only the way you increment/print it that differs.